# Why catalogs in composite roles are not working?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

When I create catalogs for SAP Fiori and later when I have to create roles with catalog access rights inside to allow users to choose apps from those catalogs.

When I now assign such a role with catalog access directly to a user it works. The user can access the catalog in the Fiori launchpad and can select an app from that catalog.

BUT: When adding that Fiori-role to a composite role and assigning that composite role to a user (instead of directly assigning it to the user), it does not work.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

kind regards
Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when your composite role has its own menu entries as described in [note 2538787](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002538787):

> Cause - Given a composite role A which includes the single roles B and C, the menu of A is composed out of B and C. However, if the composite role A has an own menu, the menu is not combined out of role B and C, only the menu of A is taken for evaluation.

Comment: Thx Greg. That was exactly the case. The composition role itself has some entries in "Menu".